# Invalid ReplaceNamedRangeContent request

Tags: google-docs-api, named-ranges

I can successfully create a name range using batchUpdate api, however, replaceNameRangeContent gives the following error:

```
{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid requests[0].replaceNamedRangeContent: Named range with ID kix.ydbik9q4xmna contains content that cannot be replaced.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }
```

The request for this was:

```
{ "requests": [ { "replaceNamedRangeContent": { "namedRangeId": "kix.ydbik9q4xmna", "text": "" } } ] }
```

Am I using the API properly?  I created the name range giving start/endindex and naming it.  It creates the NameRangeId that I used in the replace content post.

There was content in the index range above.  However, below is a sample doc structure for an empty doc (with doc styles, etc. omitted).  I tried a

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "createNamedRange": {
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 2
        },
        "name": "ApplicantName"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

followed by

```
    {
        "requests": [
        {
            "replaceNamedRangeContent": {
                "namedRangeId": "kix.f7g9w0sr3kyp",
                "text": "Applicant Name"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and get the same error.  But when doing the create named range it would not accept any start/end index besides 1 and 2.

I must not understand the actual intent of named ranges!

Sample:

```
    {
      "title": "Test mule",
      "body": {
        "content": [
          {
        "endIndex": 1,
        "sectionBreak": {
          "sectionStyle": {
            "columnSeparatorStyle": "NONE",
            "contentDirection": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
            "sectionType": "CONTINUOUS"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "startIndex": 1,
        "endIndex": 2,
        "paragraph": {
          "elements": [
            {
              "startIndex": 1,
              "endIndex": 2,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "\n",
                "textStyle": {}
              }
            }
          ],
          "paragraphStyle": {
            "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
            "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

### I can reproduce your error when creating a named range with `"startIndex": 0`

Mind that indices for paragraphs (and thus text) in Google Docs refer to the position of a character in the text and start with `1`.

So if you create a name range specifying the indices correctly, you will not get the error mesage

> { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid requests[0].replaceNamedRangeContent: Named range with ID kix.ydbik9q4xmna contains content that cannot be replaced.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }

Sample request for creating named ranges:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "createNamedRange": {
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 5,
          "endIndex": 7
        },
        "name": "test3"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  So I created a named range:

{
  "requests": [
   {
      "createNamedRange": {
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 13,
          "endIndex": 48
        },
        "name": "ApplicantName"
      }
}
  ]
}

which were the start/end indices of a paragraph.  I then did the replaceNamedRangeContent for that named range.  Is that not correct?

Comment: Previous to creating the range, was there any content from index 13 to 48? Can you share a sample doc?

Comment: Please see added detail in original post

Comment: You say: ` But when doing the create named range it would not accept any start/end index besides 1 and 2.`. But you also say that your document is empty (it has only one line break) and the highest endIndex is 2! So how do you expect to create a named range outside of the existing range?

Comment: Before you perform the `replaceNamedRange` request you need to make sure that your name range is not empty - type at leat an empty space into it.

Comment: good point :)  when you asked me if there was content in the 13 to 48 index I thought you were suggesting that was the issue.  It had content so shouldn't replaceNameRange have worked on that range?

Comment: It is ahrd to understand your issue, I can have a look at your sample doc if your want.